# My method in Java can't find the value of the variable and sets it as 0. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, methods, instance

So I have two methods:

```
public double calcAvg()
    {

        double dSum;
        dSum=iTest1+iTest2+iTest3/3;
        System.out.print(dSum);
        return dSum;
    }
```

```
public void setTestScores(int iTest1, int iTest2, int iTest3)
    {
        if(iTest1>0)
        {
            this.iTest1=iTest1;
        }
        if(iTest2>0)
        {
            this.iTest2=iTest2;
        }
        if(iTest3>0)
        {
            this.iTest3=iTest3;
        }
```

I am trying to figure out why `calcAvg()` is setting the values of `iTest1, iTest2, iTest3` as 0 after inputting the variables with values like so:
`Methods.setTestScores(90,78,83);`

EDIT Added global code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Student
{   Scanner kbAlpha=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner kbNum=new Scanner(System.in);
    String strLast;             //student's last name
    String strFirst;            //student's first name
    int iTest1;                 //test 1
    int iTest2;                 //test 2
    int iTest3;                 //test 3
    String strStreet;           //student’s street address
    String strCity;             //student’s city
    String strState;            //student’s state
    String strZip;              //student’s zip


//+Student(first:String,last:String)        //the only constructor
    public String Student(String first , String last)
    {
        return first + last;

    }


//+setName(first:String, last:String):void
    public void setName(String strFirst,String strLast)
{
    if(strFirst.equals(""))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            this.strFirst=strFirst;
        }
        if(strLast.equals(""))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            this.strLast=strLast;
        }
}//end setName (String ,String) 

//+setTestScores( t1:int,  t2:int,  t3:int):void
    public void setTestScores(int iTest1, int iTest2, int iTest3)
    {
        if(iTest1>0)
        {
            this.iTest1=iTest1;
        }
        if(iTest2>0)
        {
            this.iTest2=iTest2;
        }
        if(iTest3>0)
        {
            this.iTest3=iTest3;
        }
    }//end setTestScores(int, int, int)

//+setTest(score:int,numTest:int):void
    public void setTest(int score, int numTest)
    {
        if(numTest>=1 && numTest<=3)
        {
            switch(numTest)
            {
                case 1:
                this.iTest1=score;
            }
        }

    }//end setTest(int, int)

//+setStreet(street:String):void
    public void setStreet(String strStreet)
    {
        if(strStreet.equals(""))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            this.strStreet=strStreet;
        }
    }//end setStreet(String)

//+setCity(city:String):void
    public void setCity(String strCity)
    {
        if(strCity.equals(""))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            this.strCity=strCity;
        }
    }//end setCity(String)

//+setState(state:String):void
    public void setState(String strState)
    {
        if(strState.equals(""))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            this.strState=strState;
        }
    }//end setState(String)

//+setZip(zip:String):void
    public void setZip(String strZip)
    {
        if(strZip.equals(""))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            this.strZip=strZip;
        }
    }//end setZip(String)

//+setAddress(street:String,city:String,state:String,zip:String):void
    public void setAddress(String strStreet,String strCity,String strState,String strZip)
    {
        if(strStreet.equals(""))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            this.strStreet=strStreet;
        }
        if(strCity.equals(""))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            this.strCity=strCity;
        }
        if(strState.equals(""))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            this.strState=strState;
        }
        if(strZip.equals(""))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            this.strZip=strZip;
        }
    }//end setAddress(String,String,String,String)

//+getName():String
    public String getName()
    {
        String strName;
        strName=this.strFirst + this.strLast;
        return strName;
    }//end getName()

//+getTest(numTest:int):int
    public int getTest(int numTest)
    {

        return numTest;

    }//end getTest(int)

//+getAddress():String
    public String getAddress()
    {
        String strAddress;
        strAddress=(this.strStreet + this.strCity + this.strState + this.strZip);
        return strAddress;
    }//end getAddress()

//+getStreet():String
    public String getStreet()
    {
        String strStreet;
        strStreet=this.strStreet;
        return this.strStreet;
    }//end getStreet()

//+getCity():String
    public String getCity()
    {
        String strCity;
        strCity=this.strCity;
        return this.strCity;
    }//end getCity()

//+getState():String
    public String getState()
    {
        String strState;
        strStreet=this.strState;
        return this.strState;
    }//end getState()

//+getZip():String
    public String getZip()
    {
        String strZip;
        strZip=this.strZip;
        return this.strZip;
    }//end getZip()
//+findMax():int
//+findMin():int
//+calcAvg():double
    public double calcAvg()
    {
        //double dAvg;
        double dSum;
        dSum=(iTest1+iTest2+iTest3)/3;
        System.out.print(dSum);
        return dSum;
    }
//+studentRecord():String
    //public String studentRecord()

}
//+letterGrade():char
//+equals(s:Student):Boolean
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Proj3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Methods.setTestScores(90,78,83);
        Student MethodAvg = new Student();
        MethodAvg.calcAvg();
        }
}
```

Comment: Share the class global code

Comment: plz post your complete class... I guess `setTestScores` is a static method but that's not reflected in your posted code...

Comment: That's definitely not what's happening. Could you please show us the whole class and also the main method so we can assess what's wrong correctly? :)

Comment: calcAvg doesn't change the values of iTest1, iTest2 and iTest3. Most likely, it's just the default value

Comment: @GhostCat My professor requires us to use Hungarian notation or he deducts points off our program. I'm well aware of it.

Comment: @GhostCat If I had to guess why he makes us use Hungarian notation, it might be the fact that the man is around 60-80 years old and has been programming since the 60s and 70s. I've talked to other students and they are being taught completely different style of programming that we are being taught in his class. I just have to knock out the rest of this semester since there is only a month left.

Comment: Makes sense. Still, after you through the whole class, you *could* consider to respectfully talk to him. Sometimes people really dont understand the problems they are creating. And they really dont want to create problems. So, just saying, for the sake of future students in that place: consider talking to him later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post what `Methods` is, but I'm assuming it's an instance of `Student`. The reason why `iTest1, iTest2, iTest3` are 0 is that you are setting the values in the first `Student`, but calling `calcAvg()` on the second one, where the variables have default 0 value. Try

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setTestScores(90, 78, 83);
    student.calcAvg();
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Methods is the Student class and Proj3 is the main class. Your answer helped me solved my issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the main method, you are setting the variables in instance and calculating the average on a separate instance, try the below code it will work:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Student std = new Student();
    std.setTestScores(90,78,83);
    std.calcAvg();
}
```